# Sonarqube is Dashboard issue

Tags: sonarqube

I have been experiencing one strange issue from past 2 days. I had to setup sonarqube for code analysis and so I did it firstly in my local and then after successfully configuring, I did the same on one remote server. We are using Gradle in between.

All the configuration of sonar on remote machine (where I finally have to setup sonar so everybody can see) are same as in my local sonar instance (Means MySQl DB, Java version, Sonar version ..everything). When I check any project in sonarqube, I can see a number of bugs for my **localhost:9000** Sonar but 0 bugs for **RemoteServerIP:9000** sonar.

One thing here is, % of **Duplications**  are same on both the IPs, but the rest of the parameters are showing 0 on **RemoteServerIP:9000** sonar.

Please check following images:

***Sonar instance on my local system with same configuration:-***
[image: Sonar instance on my local system with same configuration]

***Sonar instance on my Remote system with same configuration:-***
[image]

Please let me know what I can do here to resolve the issue.

Thanks in Advance :-)

Comment: just try start remote sonarqube server with cleanning elastic search data

Comment: Hi, I tried. It didnt solve the problem. I cleared data/es folder but the issue is still there.

Comment: Can you compare the list of plugins that are installed on both instances? Looks like you are missing a language plugin on the 2nd one.

Comment: All the plugins were same. I ultimately uninstalled everything and configured again, Now it is working fine :-) Still didnt understand what was wrong previously. Thanks btw for your time :-)